# Why did the status of my paper change from "with editorial office " to "with editor" in bioinformatics journal?"

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, journal-workflow, bioinformatics

I submitted a paper in bioinformatics journal. After a five days, the status of my manuscript changed from "with editorial office " to "with editor." What does this indicate

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like-how-should-i-interpret-a Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for sharing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine it indicates that a specific editor has been assigned to deal with your paper.